# r - dplyr newbie - group_by

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataset with 20 variables and 250K rows.  I would like to add new variable, "NumAdms",  based on the number of rows in "OT_entry" per individual "patient_id".  I have constructed a dummy example:

```
 library(dplyr)

  reproeg <- names(c("patient_id", "OT_entry", "Other_1", "Other_2",
                   "Other_3"))
  reproeg$patient_id <- c(123, 123, 453, 289, 123)
  reproeg$OT_entry <- c("01/01/2012 09:30:00", "20/01/2012 08:20:00", 
                      "02/01/2012 09:40:00", "10/01/2012 11:00:00",
                      "10/02/2012 09:40:00")
  reproeg$Other_1 <- c("xy", "xy", "xy", "zh", "xy")
  reproeg$Other_2 <- c(22.3, 33.1, 22.1, 33.5, 44.2)
  reproeg$Other_3 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)

  reproeg %>%
    group_by(patient_id) %>%
    mutate(NumAdms, length(OT_entry))
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Comment: So what is your question? Where exactly are you getting stuck? What exactly is the desired output?

Comment: Sorry! I've just added the error message that I get..."Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "list""

Answer (score 3):

These days, you can also go for:

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(reproeg) %>%
     add_count(patient_id) %>%
     rename(NumAdms = n)
```

`add_count` is equivalent to condensed `group_by` and `mutate(colname = n())`, however the column name for count will be by default `n`. The advantage here is that you don't need to `ungroup()` later on, for instance.

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  patient_id OT_entry            Other_1 Other_2 Other_3 NumAdms
       <dbl> <fct>               <fct>     <dbl> <lgl>     <int>
1        123 01/01/2012 09:30:00 xy         22.3 TRUE          3
2        123 20/01/2012 08:20:00 xy         33.1 FALSE         3
3        453 02/01/2012 09:40:00 xy         22.1 FALSE         1
4        289 10/01/2012 11:00:00 zh         33.5 TRUE          1
5        123 10/02/2012 09:40:00 xy         44.2 FALSE         3
```

Comment: Cool! Never heard of add_count. When was that added?

Comment: I think about a year ago, dplyr v0.7. Yeah, it actually made life a bit easier with not having to constantly ungroup() if needed :-)

Answer (score 2):

You never defined `reproeg` as a `data.frame`, so that's the first issue.
Second, `mutate` works with `tag=value` pairs.
Third, you're not counting the `length` of `OT_entry`, but the number of cases in each group, that's better done within `mutate` using `n()`.

So your code should be:

```
data.frame(reproeg) %>%
     group_by(patient_id) %>%
     mutate(NumAdms=n())
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   patient_id [3]
  patient_id OT_entry            Other_1 Other_2 Other_3 NumAdms
       <dbl> <fct>               <fct>     <dbl> <lgl>     <int>
1        123 01/01/2012 09:30:00 xy         22.3 TRUE          3
2        123 20/01/2012 08:20:00 xy         33.1 FALSE         3
3        453 02/01/2012 09:40:00 xy         22.1 FALSE         1
4        289 10/01/2012 11:00:00 zh         33.5 TRUE          1
5        123 10/02/2012 09:40:00 xy         44.2 FALSE         3
```

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to accept!